# Mac OS running slow after Mojave install and disk appears to be corrupt

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, startup, mojave

I currently have upgrade OS Mojave on my laptop, imac at home and imac at work.  Don't ask me why I did all at once, other than not thinking straight.

After the install performance has dropped on all three of them.  The rainbow spinner continually appears even when just opening a simple file or directory.

I ran EtreCheckPro and it says that the hard drive is "corrupt" I suspect that something is going on with the file system that has it say this.  How can all 3 have corrupt drives?

I've tried the following:

- Restarting NVRAM (command, option, P, R)
- I tried restarting in safe mode then restarting so preferences would
  reset.
- Disk utility test on all 3 and it passes.
- I've considered throwing my computers out the window but thought I'd
  post here first to see if I can get any help.

Does anyone have any ideas to how I can resolve this?

EDIT: hard drive on the airbook is HDD 121GB Flash Storage it says.
Both Imac's are HDD.

Activity Monitor is stable no big jumps on cpu or memory usage.

Comment: any information on who is using CPU and memory? are those SSD iMac or HDD

Comment: Just edited it.  Hard drives are HDD except airbook is SSD.  No big cpu or memory consumption.  It just frequently gets stuck (rainbow spinning).  @Buscar웃

Comment: Thank you, one more question 5400 or 7400 rpm drives ? Also open Activity monitor and check your Disk usage it should settle <100k read/write and peak to 1MB. Know that it might take >2 days for Spotlight to finish. If you are interested in knowing what does it, open the console and monitor it during slow down.

Comment: How can I tell if it's 5400 or 7400?  Activity monitor shows some programs responsive and unresponsive.  In example when I open illustrator it turns red and after a while it goes normal.  Disk says kernel_task = 144.14GB / launchd 67.32GB / bird 66.05GB those are by far the largest.  @Buscar웃

Comment: something called OtherUsersExtnsio is taking up 99.8 CPU and sysmond is taking up 39.9 at random times.  @Buscar웃

Comment: Not much cpu or memory being used but program is not responsive @Buscar웃

Comment: In about this mac can tell you which drive you have (if 5400 rpm) then that is your problem. Kernel task should not be more that 2GB, so the others. You have something going on. There is no "OtherUsersExtension" on a Mac. Shut down all non Apple apps to test.

Comment: Ya it's 5400, anything I can do about it?  @Buscar웃

Comment: if you want to spend money you can replace it with SSD type and see your iMac fly. Check this out and more https://everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/imac-aluminum-tapered-edge-faq/how-to-upgrade-imac-hard-drive-aluminum-2012-2013.html

Comment: Can I get an external and run it like that or would it be too slow?  This iMac is a pain to open up.  @Buscar웃

Comment: Sorry, I have to end this conversation, this is not the place to continue, it is only for comments.

Comment: The author of etrecheck hangs out here:  https://discussions.apple.com/community/mac_os/mojave